Clarifying the confusion in understanding the friendship theorem
I have known Friendship theorem for a long time and have always had a problem with it, please help me understand the theorem of friendship correctly.
The friendship theorem states that if there is a group of people and every two friends have a mutual friend, there will be a person who is a friend to all the people in that group.
The graph of this theorem is usually likened to a windmill, but my problem is with other graphs that verify the data of the friendship theorem but do not achieve what is required, in the sense that every two friends already have a mutual friend but not necessarily someone who is friends with everyone, Here's an example of the graphs I mean:

I know that a great mathematician like Paul Erdos is unlikely to overlook such a situation, and you cannot miss this observation about the mathematical community so I think I have a misunderstanding of the text of the friendship theorem, I would be happy if I got rid of the doubts I have.

Your graph does not satisfy the hypotheses.

Persons 2 and 7 don’t have a mutual (labelled left to right, up to down).

Please explain the matter in a full answer, I really did not understand it, can the conditions be clearly stated and what condition was violated @Randall

With your edits my comment should read persons 1 and 6. But there are  other examples too.

I can't see a reason to downvote this question.  OP has confusion over the theorem, knows that they are likely wrong, and wants to understand why.  They even gave a possible counterexample and asked to be told why it's wrong.

As the comment said，your graph does not satisfy the hypotheses.It's easy to find two people don't have a mutual friend.


But A and B are not friends

You are misunderstanding the statement of the theorem.  It states that all pairs of people have a friend in common, not all pairs of friends.  I read this directly from the link you gave in your question.

Thank you, now the misunderstanding is gone

As the comments stated the uppermost vertex and the bottom-most vertex do not have a neighbor in common. Hence, it does not meet the criteria that every two vertices have exactly one neighbor, and is not a friendship graph, as you pointed out.

Does this mean that every two people should have a mutual friend and not every two friends should have a mutual friend?

I think this is a language issue.
